# AJAX request works locally, gives 500 error on server

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, server

I try to invoke my controller by using an AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    datatype: "JSONP",
    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteTeam", "Team")',
    cache: false,
    data: { 
        "id": teamId, 
        "id2": locationName 
    },
    success: function (html) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

It works on my localhost but doesn't work on the server. I'm sure there is no difference code between local and server.

I get a 500 internal error. After looking into the error, I found it is on
`xhr.send( ( options.hasContent && options.data ) || null )`. I don't understand why it doesn't work on the server.

Comment: A 500 error means the problem is occurring on your server. The JS code is not the problem. Check the data that's being sent, and also check the network tab of the console. Normally there is a full debug message in the response text

Comment: what I don't understand is that why it works on my local but not on server. If there are bugs, it should not work on my local, right?

Comment: Not if the bugs are to do with the implementation of the server. You need to debug the server side code